# How do I get the Websocket host from the onmessage msg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I have multiple websocket servers that are communicating with a single page, and I'm running a list of callbacks to handle onmessage events from the servers. In order to reuse some functions for debugging I want to know where the messages are coming from from the msg object.

...

```
socket1Callbacks = $.Callbacks();
socket2Callbacks = $.Callbacks();
socket1Callbacks.add(logIncoming);
socket2Callbacks.add(logIncoming);
```

...

```
socket1.onmessage = function (msg) {
   socket1Callbacks.fire(msg);
};
socket2.onmessage = function (msg) {
    socket2Callbacks.fire(msg);
};
```

...

```
function logIncoming(msg) {
    console.log('MSG FROM HOST:' + msg.????host????);
    console.log('Recieved: ' + msg.data);
}
```

Comment: where is `socket1Callbacks.add` defined? it's probably not forwarding `this` correctly, like a native-bound event would. you could try `event.target`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the incoming message callback:

```
socket2.onmessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(this.url); // the connected host
};
```

If you want need it inside logIncoming function, simply wrap the incoming message with your own object, containing the host:

```
socket2.onmessage = function (msg) {
    socket2Callback.fire({ host: this.url, data: msg });
};
```

And then

```
function logIncoming(msg) {
    console.log('MSG FROM HOST:' + msg.host);
    console.log('Received: ' + msg.data);
}
```

Comment: this works within the onmessage callback, like you said. I'm wondering if there's any way to get it in the logIncoming callback, where this suggestion doesn't work.